# How to record Application in ipad IOS5

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5

i want to record my app in ipad is there any esay way to do it or any free screen recoder app which can record it plz help me out.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**DisplayRecorder**](http://rpetri.ch/cydia/displayrecorder/) if you have a jailbroken device. Other than being jailbroken, you can try using mirroring if you have a compatible device and the proper hardware.

Comment: No, as it is listed when you follow that link, it's $4.99.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with recording from the simulator, the built-in QuickTime app can record (a part of) your screen with ease.

If you are looking for a way to record video from your app on the device, I have previously done [so with some success](https://github.com/evolvIQ/iqwidgets-presentationkit). No App Store for that function though, and I haven't tried it on iOS5.

If you want to record the whole device screen (i.e. not just your app), you can take a look at using AirPlay Mirroring to an AppleTV and some recording hardware to record the HDMI stream. The AirPlay Mirroring protocol is not (yet) cracked so there are no software recorders for AirPlay Mirroring yet.